# Reader keeps returning System.Data.SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm writing a program for bank accounts, in which people register an account and get their own bank account.

Right now my data reader keeps returning some weird argument in my label.

```
public void Saldo()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jobva\source\repos\Fundamentals\Fundamentals\bin\Debug\BankOfFontys.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand myCommand2 = con.CreateCommand();
    myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT saldo FROM Account WHERE gebruikersnaam ='" + naam + "'";
    myCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataReader reader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();

    saldoLbl.Text = Convert.ToString(reader2);
}
```

This is my code, but for some reason it doesn't return an actual value, also am I using the correct version in the command, the "naam" is a string which has the username the person entered, and it should only search in the column in which that username matches the string.

How does this work?

Comment: This is full of mistakes. You need to get an ADO.NET book or tutorial, this stuff is too complicated to guess your way through it.

Comment: The reason that `Convert.ToString(reader2)` is returning "system.data.sqldatareader" is because that's the fully-qualified type name of your `reader2` object.  In general, what you actually want to do is call methods on your objects, not try to convert them to strings.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, micro-orm's like Dapper are much better at this, much easier to use (far less code), and less prone to type conversion errors and security problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the value from your reader, after reading a line (and checking if there actually is one). In the following code example I assumed your saldo is an integer value.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jobva\source\repos\Fundamentals\Fundamentals\bin\Debug\BankOfFontys.mdf;Integrated Security=True")) {
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader2.Read()) {
        saldoLbl.Text = reader2.GetInt32(0).ToString();
    }
    reader2.Close();
}
```

It might be a good idea to read the docs as this are the basics of using SQL in C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

From there you can also learn about [ExecuteScalar()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) what might be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: He also needs to learn about `IDisposable`, `using`, and parameters. I understand your desire to help, but giving beginners code they don't understand to drop in to their application teaches them bad habits.

Comment: This works thanks! Also, the part where I input my SQL Command, I"m using "naam" as a string I defined earlier, does it work like that, or how do I put my defined string inside of the "..." with it still having effect.

Comment: I totally agree @DourHighArch, I also strongly recommend learning the basics like mentioned. Just to give a little basic I added the using and close - part.

Comment: @JobvanRoozendaal Please read about the usage of SQL parameters in C#, the way it's done in your code is very dangerous and prone to SQL injection attacks. It's in the article I linked in my answer. Or better, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2) as the other example is for Oracle.